# Need to get id instead of selected value in modelchoicefield django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

This is a very very basic question and i have already searched and tried lots of ways to do it but i want to know the good practice/best method to go about it.

There is a table in which i am trying to store the user selected code from another table. What is want is

A model form combo box which shows `description` field value while saves its respective `pos_code` in the table.

This is my model and forms:

```
pos_code = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Positions.objects)
```

Here i want to insert the `pos_code` against the user selected `description`:

```
class TmpPlInvoice(models.Model):
    voucher_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=10)
    pos_code = models.ForeignKey(Positions, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='pos_code', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tmp_pl_invoice'
```

I'm getting the choice field from this model:

```
class Positions(models.Model):                                      

    pos_code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'positions'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description
```

But it gives me `description` instead of `pos_code`. I know that I am returning description but I need to show it to user and get code in the views.

Here is my full form

```
class TmpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    description = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Positions.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = TmpPlInvoice
        exclude = ['net_amt', 'post_date', 'address', 'posted', 'voucher_date', 'particulars']
```

**What i have**
[IMG]http://i68.tinypic.com/zj89yx.jpg[/IMG]
Current form output
{'voucher_id': u'3452345', 'description': Positions: Premier Industrial Chemicals}

I can't use this 'description'. I need to save the code of Premier Industrial Chemicals in my TmpForm

**What i need**
[IMG]http://i66.tinypic.com/nh0x2a.jpg[/IMG]

Desired form output
{'voucher_id': u'3452345', 'pos_code': 0001}

Comment: Really need you help guys :( Any suggestion would do.

Comment: @e4c5 I have posted my full form.

Comment: @e4c5 do you mean return obj.pos_code?

Comment: @e4c5 returning obj.pos_code works fine. On the ui, the codes appear and in the views the description is received. form  is {'voucher_id': u'52352', 'description': <Positions: Premier Industrial Chemicals>} I want the exact opposite. Description in the ui and code in views.

Comment: @e4c5 On the ui, the codes appear and in the views the description is received. I want the exact opposite. I want to show user the choices like 'chemical mill', 'paper factory' and save the code of 'chemical factory' or 'paper mill' in the form. Right now my form output in the views is {'voucher_id': u'52352', 'description': <Positions: Premier Industrial Chemicals>}. I want to get code of the Premier Industrial Chemicals i.e {'voucher_id': u'52352', 'description': 000115}.

Comment: This is my current output. I need to show description instead of codes . [IMG]http://i68.tinypic.com/x6ekbc.png[/IMG]

Comment: Well, then it's a simple matter of returning the description field instead! Plese see updated answer

Comment: I tried that. The output is exactly the same. I do not understand why.

Comment: Sorry for confusing statement. I mean that the print is showing list of choices. obj is returing. But my issue still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This model form saved my life. The MyModelChoiceField class shows the label but send id on the backend.

```
class MyModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.description


class TmpFormm(forms.ModelForm):
    pos_code = MyModelChoiceField(queryset=Positions.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select2_single form-control', 'blank': 'True'}))
```